# jQuery change state of active class icons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an active state using icons for my drop-down list. Basically it should show both the + icons when the li is non-active and then show the - icon for when the li is active and vice versa.

**JsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/uzrbbqx9/1/

```
$('#cssmenu > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
if (checkCookie != "") {
$('#cssmenu > li > a:eq(' + checkCookie + ')').addClass('active').next().show();
}
checkCookie = $.cookie("sub_nav-item");
if (checkCookie != "") {
$('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a:eq(' + checkCookie +        ')').addClass('active').next().show();
}


$('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a').click(function () {
var navIndex = $('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a').index(this);
$.cookie("sub_nav-item", navIndex);
var checkElement = $(this).next();


$(this).removeClass('testing');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('testing');
$('#cssmenu li li .active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});

$('#cssmenu > li > a').click(function () {
var navIndex = $('#cssmenu > li > a').index(this);
$.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
$('#cssmenu li ul').slideUp();


if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
} else {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
}
$('#cssmenu li a').removeClass('active');

$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you need help removing the 'active' class when collapsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uzrbbqx9/2/

In your click event the activeClass method was always being fired, directly after the removeClass method.  I moved them into the if statement like so:

```
if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass('active');
} else {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $('#cssmenu li a').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your click event handler you can do a few things. You can check if the menu is currently animating with `:animated` jQuery selector, and/or you can `stop()` any animations in progress. In my example I chose to ignore the click if it is already animating. Second, because of the animation, the `:visible` selector can give some false positive/negatives when the button is clicked rapidly so you should cue off something else, like the active class:

```
$('#cssmenu > li > a').click(function () {
    var $a = $(this),
        $ul = $a.next(),
        navIndex = $('#cssmenu > li > a').index(this);

    if ($ul.is(':animated'))
        return;

    $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
    $('#cssmenu li a.active').not(this).removeClass('active').next().stop().slideUp();

    $ul.stop().slideToggle();
    $a.toggleClass('active');

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzrbbqx9/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Works perfectly. One more question. If I was to go to the pricing page (under online booking) from google how could I make the list be open with the pricing li active? At the moment it works when just going through the site normally and adds active class but if a user was to access this page from google it will need to know that it's on this page and make the list open...

Comment: It would be very similar to your checkCookie function. Only instead of checking the cookie it would check `window.location.search` or `window.location.hash` or however else you want to send the data. If this check passes you can set the cookie to match then let your checkCookie do its thing.

Comment: Hey @malk thanks again. Would this be a matter of replicating the current cookie functions that I have already got?